# C# hangs on "Managed to native Transition" when there is no such transition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, xna

I recently upgraded my main dev machine to Win 7, Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4, and XNA 4.0. I had to port a bunch of my XNA code, as there were breaking changes from 3.1-> 4.

Everything in my solution compiles now, but I am getting really strange hangs at odd times. I've tried with several projects, and the symptom is that it will consistently hang on some method call, and the stack trace will show the top of the stack as being "Managed to Native Transition". This is very strange, as these are very simple method calls in managed code. A simplified example is as follows:

```
public class ShadowWindows: Game {
    // other methods

    protected override void Initialize() {
        //bunch of initialization
        InitModels();
        InitRenderer();
    }

    protected void InitModels() {
        //do a bunch of stuff
    }
}
```

The above code hangs on the "InitModels()" call. If I use the debugger I can't step into the method, it will just hang if I try to do so.

Any ideas? It's almost as if there's some sort of corruption going on. The problem doesn't seem ratioanl to me.

Thanks,
Garth

Comment: The transitions must be in the XNA library. I don't know about XNA, but I know parts of the BCL wrap the Windows API. I see oodles of managed to native transitions while debugging my winforms apps.

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on the call to InitModels() and hit F11, will it eventually step into the method? what happens? how long does that take ?

Comment: I think you need to post more information before anyone can really try to answer this. But as a vague guess - are you doing GPU stuff in `Initialize` (and functions that it calls) that should really be done in `LoadContent`?

Comment: Hi all, I looked into this further. If I try to step in it never gets there. It just sits spinning it's wheels endlessly.

I did make a discovery. The hang only happens when a particular class the game is using has virtual methods. If I take out the "virtual" keyword from the method definitions then it runs ok. Note that these methods aren't actually being called. Just the fact that virtual methods exist is enough to cause the problem.

By the way, I did try moving everything into LoadContent and nothing changed.

Any ideas?
Thanks.